# whats the difference between Audience Builder Vs Filtered data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

On going through documentation, it seems that what is been done through Audience Builder can also be done through Filtered Data Extensions. Kindly clarify use cases where Audience Builder is used vs Filtered Data extension.

Answer (score 0):

Filtered Data extension is more Data Extension specific. You would have to create specific filters for every data extensions you have.

Audience builder is more subscriber specific. It listens to the subscribers data and slices and groups subscribers based on dimensions. This is a very useful tool if you have subscriber data in different sources and want to build a subscriber data base based on specific attribute/dimension

Having said that, if your data model is in such a way that you use a data extension to save all your subscriber data, there is no specific difference in Filetered DE and Audience builder

Answer (score 0):

There are few key differences between using filters/filtered DE's and Audience Builder.

Scale would be the first one to mention, when your contact base goes above 1M and you have a lot of additional data that need to be used in segmentation filtered DE's will eventually hit the limits from the time perspective.

Second to it the Audience Builder is actually exposing factual dimensions for the purpose of data segmentation, it takes a way technical complexity when building sophisticated conditions while defining audience and segment.

Through the use of different types of dimensions the data can be transformed into a very marketing user friendly values, something they can operate with but without getting into technical aspects. Have a look at this page that provides an overview with some samples to understand how users would use the attributes for segmentation purposes, it differs from standard drag-n-drop segmentation you use with filters: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/audience_builder/attribute_library/